# Wacom bamboo capture CTH470L pen and touch doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, wacom, graphics-tablet, bamboo

i bought a wacom bamboo capture, it lights up, and shows in lsusb but it isn't working, i read some topics here but don't get any luck :/

ps: sorry about my english i'm brazilian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed this guide http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562 and have managed my wacom to work, i hope it will be usefull for someone